# Nautilus video search not showing webm

Tags: gnome, nautilus, video, search, webm

Using the Nautilus search for videos shows mp4 and wmv but not webm. It generates thumbnails for webm, and I can play webm fine. However, for some reason, nautilus doesn't think webm is a type of video.  Is there a way to designate webm files as a video for the purposes of nautilus search?

Comment: What version of nautilus do youy have? My `3.26.4` shows webm just fine

Comment: 3.32.1-0ubuntu0.19.04.0.  Again, it shows webm fine in folders but it doesn't consider it a video when I choose the "video" dropdown option for search.  Obviously if I search for '.webm' it will find them, but I want to use the "video" dropdown to get everything(wmv,mp4,webm,etc) together in one search.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified that I search with the dropdown->video.